# Which http error status code should i use?

Tags: postgresql, rest, http, internal-server-error, bad-request

this error is when client request insert data to database with user id params (this user id is constraint to table books which i want to insert). so, should i send bad request or internal server error? if the answer is internal server error one, should i edit error message to send to client? or i just send pure error message from sql error?

the error message : `ERROR: insert or update on table "books" violates foreign key constraint "books_user_id_fkey" (SQLSTATE 23503)`

Answer (score 1):

I would pass back a general 500 error. However, do rewrite the error message that you pass back to the client. There's no point in giving your users more information about your system then necessary, and secondly it avoids the temptation to just catch the error in an exception and forward it to the client, such error messages may leak vulnerability information to the public